# Update value in a table with value from another table in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have `tbltransfer` which contains `location` and `eq_id`. I would like to change the value of `location` in `tblequipments` with the value of `location` from `tbltransfer` where `eq_id` in `tblequipments` is equal to the `eq_id` in `tbltransfer`. This the query that I came up with:

```
UPDATE tblequipments 
    SET LocationName = (
        SELECT t.Location from tbltransfer as t 
        join tblequipments as e on t.eq_ID = e.eq_ID 
        WHERE t.transactionID=%s
    )
```

Comment: @Flubba I'm looking for the correct query that will perform the scenario that I stated above

Answer (score 1):

mysql will run subquery for each row in update statement. It is better to use join here:

```
UPDATE
    tblequipments,
    tbltransfer
SET
    tblequipments.location = tbltransfer.location
WHERE
    tblequipments.eq_id = tbltransfer.eq_id
AND
    tbltransfer.transactionID = %s
```

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE tblequipments
INNER JOIN tbltransfer ON tblequipments.eq_ID = tbltransfer.eq_ID 
SET tblequipments.LocationName=tbltransfer.Location
WHERE tbltransfer.transactionID=%s
```